# How to add an additional type to the ASP.NET script manager so that the script is generated?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

When I add a service reference to my script manager, all the required C# classes are generated in the script, but one. This particular class is used as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject {
  [DataMember]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public bool Value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyData {
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public List<MyObject> ObjectInfo { get; set; }
}

[WebService]
[ScriptService]
public class MyService {
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
  public void AddNewData(IEnumerable<MyData> dataObjects) {
    ... some code
  }
}
```

No script is generated for the class MyObject. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [GenerateScriptType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.generatescripttypeattribute.aspx) attribute to your web service.

```
[WebService]
[ScriptService]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(MyObject))]
public class MyService {
}
```

I found this in Chapter 5 (page 157) of [ASP.NET AJAX in Action](http://www.manning.com/gallo/).